# XPath query to identify untagged text

Tags: xpath

Consider this HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h3>item 1</h3>
          text details for item 1
        <h3>item 2</h3>
          text details for item 2
        <h3>item 3</h3>
          text details for item 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not terribly familiar with XPath, but it seems to me that there is no notation which will match the "text details" sections individually. Can you confirm?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two correct XPath expressions that select exactly the wanted text nodes.

Comment: SimpleXMLElement::xpath from PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: Don't know that one. Its important to state the parser, as each can have its own implementation details. What works in one, might not necessarily work in another. Each should be equal, but no always.

Comment: Heh, yes, I've now learned that. Filed for future reference. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/html/body/table/tr/td/h3/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

This means: Get the first following sibling text node of every `h3` element that is a child of every `tr` element that is a child of every `table` element that is a child of every `body` element that is a child of the `html` top element.

**Or, if you only know that the wanted text nodes are the immediate following siblings of all `h3` elements** in the docunent, then tis XPath expression selects them:

```
//h3/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Comment: Hmm, this gives me three matches -- but each match is identical, contains the entire <TD> (as if I had selected '//td'), and reports four children -- an H1 and three H3s. The text sections do not show up.

Comment: @Alex Howansky: This selects the three text nodes, the same as `//td/text()` with your example. Recheck your results.

Comment: @Alex Howansky: No, these expression select exactly the three text nodes you want. You need to verify your results.

Comment: Rechecked, this does not work in PHP v5.3.3 SimpleXMLElement::xpath(). It doesn't seem to like the "text()" selector. I reimplemented the same query using Perl's XML::XPath and bingo, works no problem. Stupid thing, wasted a day on that damn bug! Thanks Dimitre. Off to file a PHP bug report...

Comment: And it also works fine when using PHP's DOMXPath class. <shakes fist at SimpleXML>

Answer (score 1):

in the world of Xml/Xpath

Text - is a type of Element Node.

so considering your example

TD has 7 child nodes

TD.getChild(3) should return the "text details for item 1" Value.

in XPath
$x//table/tr/td/text()[1]

Comment: I'm only getting 4 children for this query. :(

Comment: If I wrap the text lines with <p> I get 7 children as expected. But unfortunately I can't touch the original HTML.

Comment: Why the variable/parameter reference `$x`?

Comment: Its a pseudo code. generally '$' is keyword for any variable in XQuery World. i used that. assume $x is the Xml Content