# XPath Query to Find All Untagged Text Throughout HTML Document

Tags: xml, xpath, css-selectors

Given the following HTML, is there an XPath query that will extract all the tagged and untagged text between the two `<h2>` tags? (I am using the `RSelenium` package in RStudio.)

```
<html>
    <h2 id="section1" class="article">Heading 1</h2>
    <h3 id="section1.1" class="article">Subheading 1</h3>
    <p id="para001"  class="article section clear">
           Paragraph text 1.</p> 
    <div id="formula1" class="formula">...<img />...</div>
           Untagged text 1.
    <sub>  Subscripted text. </sub>
           Untagged text 2. 
    <em>   Emphasized text. </em>
           Untagged text 3.
    <span id="bib"> Bibliography text. </span>
           Untagged text 4.
    <p id="para002" class="article section clear">
           Paragraph text 2.</p>
    <h3 id="section1.2" class="article">Subheading 2</h3>
    <p id="para003" class="article section clear">
           Paragraph 3 text.</p>
    <h3 id="section1.3" class="article">Subheading 3</h3>
    <p id="para004" class="article section clear">
           Paragraph 4 text.</p>
    <h2 id="section2" class="article">Heading 2</h2>       
</html>
```

I'm trying to come up with a query that will return:

```
Paragraph text 1.
Untagged text 1.
Subscripted text.
Untagged text 2. 
Emphasized text.
Untagged text 3.
Bibliography text.
Untagged text 4.
Paragraph text 2.
Paragraph text 3.
Paragraph text 4.
```

What I've tried so far is,

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h2[@id='section1'] 
    and following-sibling::h2[@id='section2'] 
    and descendant::node()]
```

which returns,

```
Paragraph text 1.
Paragraph text 2.
Paragraph text 3.
Paragraph text 4.
```

I tried using the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083466/xpath-query-to-identify-untagged-text), but my problem is a little more complex. I tried adding `following-sibling::text()[1]`, but it doesn't extract the untagged text. If there's not a good XPath solution, then I would gladly welcome alternative methods like CSS selectors.

Comment: There are some apparent typos in your example (the p-tag on line 4, the id-attribute of the last h2-tag and your XPath refering to h3 instead of h2). You should fix this so the code can execute unaltered.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I made those corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you don't want to filter for only p-tags (which is what `p` in the third letter does), you want all tags after section1 and before section 2. And second, you are looking for all decendants of the tags between these two which are text-nodes.

So: looking for all tags which have `preceding-sibling::h2[@id='section1']` and `following-sibling::h2[@id='section2']`:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::h2[@id='section1'] and following-sibling::h2[@id='section2']]
```

And then looking for all `text()`-tags below any of these:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::h2[@id='section1'] and following-sibling::h2[@id='section2']]//text()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your XPath is correct, but the RSelenium package is returning an error saying that "Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS)." I'll need to take some time to see why it's misinterpreting that XPath query.